# NtQuerySystemInformation Hook Failure

Tags: c++, api, winapi, hook

After successfully building a trampoline and learning more about process memory space, I tested the trampoline on MessageBoxA. It worked perfectly so I decided to finally put the code to the use it was supposed to be for in the first place, hiding a process by hooking NtQuerySystemInformation. The redirect function should work fine, but the code I used to write the jmp instruction now causes the task manager to crash every time.

```
        BYTE tmpJMP[5] = {0xE9,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00}; //jmp,A,D,D,R
        memcpy(JMP,tmpJMP,5);
        DWORD Addr = ((DWORD)func - ((DWORD)oNtQuerySystemInformation + 0x5));

        for (int i=0;i<4;++i)
            JMP[i+1] = ((BYTE*)&Addr)[i];

        if (VirtualProtect((LPVOID)oNtQuerySystemInformation,5,PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE,&oldProtect) == FALSE)
            MessageBox(NULL,L"Error unprotecting memory",L"",MB_OK);

        memcpy(oldBytes,(LPVOID)oNtQuerySystemInformation,5);

        if (!WriteProcessMemory(GetCurrentProcess(),(LPVOID)oNtQuerySystemInformation,(LPCVOID)JMP,5,NULL))
            MessageBox(NULL,L"Unable to write to process memory space",L"",MB_OK);

        VirtualProtect((LPVOID)oNtQuerySystemInformation,5,oldProtect,NULL);

        FlushInstructionCache(GetCurrentProcess(),NULL,NULL);
```

I'm writing to the memory as such. I can't seem to find a problem with the code. I was thinking that maybe the memory changes from API to API but I was told that's incorrect, making me all out confused. Is there anything wrong that you all see? Please be descriptive. I love to learn o3o

Comment: Beyond evil. This code effectively tries to hook NtQuerySystemInformation. The most popular reason to do so is to hide a process from enumeration, a common albeit useless attempt at subverting anti-malware or system monitoring software. I see one bug in this straight away, but if you're in a business that legitimately needs to do this, so should you. If you're not...

Comment: I am not part of a company persay. I am a student currently and am designing a child protection program (not part of an assignment or anything like that. It's just me trying to put the knowledge that I have to profitable use.) I can't truly prove lack of malicious intent but that's my purpose. I am not trying to subvert monitoring software. This is the monitoring software

Comment: Just run yourself as a dll loaded by svchost rather than hide your own process.

Comment: @RockoLetbark: Look up rootkits and then you'll see how this ideal is generally accepted as malicious.

Comment: I know it could be considered malicious and I know why.

Comment: @HansPassant: If antivirus hide own process, is this still evil code or not? Please, dont write this comments.